# how to query on particular keys in couchbase through java client?

Tags: java, couchbase

I am new to CouchBase. I have few simple documents as :

```
1. {
  "docType": "DeviceData",
  "id": "57 0F 75 00 C8 0B@2013-06-26 23:59:38.979",
  "time": 1372271378979,
  "group": "London"
}

2. {
  "docType": "DeviceData",
  "id": "57 0F 75 00 C8 0B@2013-06-27 10:02:46.197",
  "time": 1372307566197,
  "group": "Bristol"
}

3. {
  "docType": "DeviceData",
  "id": "57 0F 75 00 C8 0B@2013-06-27 10:03:36.4",
  "time": 1372307616400,
  "group": "Bristol"
}
```

I have requirement to query on group and time. for example I want to fetch all the documents with group = Bristol and time from 1372307616100 to 1372307616500. So i deal I should get the 2 of the 3 docs.

So i have create the view as:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(doc.docType == "DeviceData")
  emit([doc.group, doc.time], doc);
}
```

And in the java code setting the query as below:

```
String str = "[\"Bristol\", 1372307566100]";
        String end = "[\"Bristol\", 1372307616500]";
        query.setRange(str, end);
        List<DeviceData> deviceData = cbStore.getView("getDevices", DeviceData.class, query);
```

But getting zero documents.

Please let me know is there anything wrong I am doing? need help thanks.

**EDIT:*
I tried using complexkeys as well like below but no luck.

```
ComplexKey startKey = ComplexKey.of("Bristol", "1372307566100");
ComplexKey endKey = ComplexKey.of("Bristol", "1372307616500");
```

Comment: 1. Try to check what value of `Stale` param is used. And try to set it to `Stale=false`.
2. Check if you have published your view.
3. Check view with same params in Couchbase web admin panel. If it returns correct values then problem is in your app, not couchbase.

Comment: i have published the view, i am able to get the records when tried using REST url.

Comment: And what about `Stale` param? As I remember it should go like `query.setStale(Stale stale)`.

PS: By the way, don't include docs in your view like: `emit([doc.group, doc.time], doc);`. It's better to use `emit([doc.group, doc.time], null);` and add `IncludeDocs` into your query: `query.setIncludeDocs(boolean include)`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that in your objects time is a long, not a String:

```
query.setStale(Stale.FALSE);
long firstParameter=1372307566197l;
long secondParameter=1372307616400l;
//["Bristol",1372307566197]
ComplexKey startKey = ComplexKey.of("Bristol", firstParameter);
//["Bristol",1372307616400]
ComplexKey endKey = ComplexKey.of("Bristol",  secondParameter);
query.setRange(startKey, endKey);
ViewResponse result = client.query(view, query);
Iterator<ViewRow> iter = result.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    ViewRow row = iter.next();      
    System.out.println( row.getId()); // ID of the document
    System.out.println(row.getKey()); // Key of the view row
    System.out.println(row.getValue()); // Value of the view row
    System.out.println(row.getDocument()); // Full document if included
    }
```