# how can i sort data on a particular column in Couchbase?

Tags: java, couchbase

hi i am new to couchbase. I have a view like below:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(doc.docType == "DeviceData")
  emit([doc.group, doc.time], [doc.node, doc.node_gps_lat, doc.node_gps_long]);
}
```

So i want have to get the result which is sorted by doc.node value. I searched the documentation but couldnot find the proper solution.

Please need help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Couchbase sorting results by key. So in your example results will be sorted firstly by `doc.group` and then by `doc.time`. If you want to sort results by `doc.node`, you should include that field in key or sort result on client/app side.

If you're quering your view with some time range (you have `startkey` and `endkey` that differs by `doc.time` param like in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343782/how-to-query-on-particular-keys-in-couchbase-through-java-client)) ordering by doc.node is only possible on client/app side. If you want to sort on couchbase side - try to change your data model.

Here is a [doc](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-writing-querying-ordering.html) that explains ordering in couchbase. And here is [doc](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-writing-map.html) with explanation how couchbase sorts view results.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm adding to what m03geek said above in that in order to sort by a particular column (value in CB), you need to pass that value back as the key(s). I'm building a Django app using CB and I wanted to sort by create date so I created the following view map function.

```js
function (doc, meta) {
 if (doc.type && doc.type == "snapshot" && doc.published == "yes" && doc.section == "sports") {
  var arrDate = doc.create_date.split("-");
           var newDate = new Date(arrDate[2], arrDate[0], arrDate[1]);
           var numTime = newDate.getTime();
           doc.time = numTime;
           emit(doc.time, null);
 }
}
```

In the map function above, I turn the string create date into a numerical time and then emit that as the key which sorts the results by create date.